# Material elevation not working after clipping

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

`Material` widget's `elevation` not working after wrapping it into `ClipPath`.

Before clipping.

[image: before-clipping]

After clipping.

[image: after-clipping]

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Here is my code.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: MyCustomClipper(),
            child: Material(
              child: SizedBox(height: 100.0, width: 100.0),
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              elevation: 8.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double x = size.width;
    double y = size.height;
    Path path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, y)
      ..lineTo(x, y - 20.0)
      ..lineTo(x, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, 0)
      ..close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: That's the expected behavior. You don't want to clip, but to change the shape. See `shape` property of `Material`

Comment: I have seen `shape` property of `Material` that takes an abstract type of `ShapeBorder` and there are some predefined shapes like `OutlineInputBorder` but i want only this shape with elevation and creating this shape i have to extend `ShapeBorder` and override some methods of it. It is little bit hard. Is there any other way to achieve this shape with elevation?

Comment: @RémiRousselet so there is no way to have elevation shadow and custom clipped shape of material?

Comment: @frozzyk Yes. Clipping does not differentiate between the shadow and the content. You need a solution that is not clip based

Comment: @rémi-rousselet Do you know any?

Answer (score 3):

I had the very same problem.

here is what I did, wrap the ClipPath widget inside Material Widget,

give color as --> Colors.transparent, //this is very important

set --> elevation:100

Here is output of my own ClipPath bottom Nav Bar
[image]

Hope it helps someone.